# Dart Exception: Already registered (Polymer) prototype for element x

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I've two polymer elements that share the same dart file. In the dart file I declare both the PolymerElement classes.

Until polymer 0.15.0+1 it was working fine.
I've updated the project to polymer 0.15.1 and now I get this exception:

```
Exception: Already registered (Polymer) prototype for element x
```

Where x is the first polymer.

I think the polymer transformer is trying to register it two times, the first scanning the x polymer html file, the second when scanning the other element html file.

An issue has been open in dart: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21332

Comment: I think you should file a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new

Comment: Done: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been "resolved" with the release 0.15.1+2 of [Polymer Dart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer).

The compiler now throws a warning, and as stated in the [issue comments](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21332): "The real solution for you here should be to put your script file in its own html file, and import that instead of your script. In summary you have to create an HTML file (e.g. script_thats_used_multiple_times.html)  with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="application/dart" src="script_thats_used_multiple_times.dart"></script>
```

then of course delete the original  from all polymer components that used this file previously and put the import above the

```
<link rel="import" href="script_thats_used_multiple_times.html">
```

which will import previously created HTML file. Simple."

Comment: "The real solution for you here should be to put your script file in its own html file, and import that instead of your script." WHAT IS THE REAL SOLUTION FOR ALL DART USERS? I am experiencing the same issues now although it is reported as being 'resolved'. The suggested solution can't be the THE SOLUTION. I HAD my script file as part of my html file before. I was advised on this same forum to separate them as I would be able to use more of dart tooling such as break points etc to solve issues; and these are logical. Now to hear to do the opposite!. Help us get it right please.

Comment: I think they meant to say each HTML file should have his own dart script and import it. I will ask for more clarification.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about Dart and whatnot, but I had the same error message in my console. Turns out I was still having the `noscript` attribute in my element declaration, which is wrong if you want to register your element manually.
Removing `noscript` from the element declaration solved the problem.