# Exception: Already registered (Polymer) prototype for element h-select-item (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:170)

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Since polymer 0.15.1 I have been stuck with the following exception on attempting to run my application.

My entry point is

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ePIMSS Shared</title>

    <!-- include the web_components polyfills with support for Dart. -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="epimss_shared.css">

    <link href = '../lib/component/description_form.html' rel = 'import'>
    <link href = '../lib/component/unit_form.html' rel = 'import'>



  </head>
  <body  unresolved >

    <h1>Description!</h1>
    <description-form label = 'Labelling'
      data-receiver = 'description-form --> epimss-shared'>
    </description-form>

    <!-- bootstrap polymer -->
    <script type="application/dart">
      export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My unit_form.html is

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link href = '../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html' rel = 'import' >

<link href = '../../../packages/paper_elements/paper_item.html' rel = 'import' >

<link href = '../../../packages/html_components/input/select_item.html' rel = 'import' >
<link href = '../../../packages/html_components/input/select_checkbox_menu.html' rel = 'import' >

<link href = '../../../packages/paper_elements/paper_dropdown_menu.html' rel = 'import' >

<polymer-element name = 'unit-form'>
  <template>
    <style>
      #select-chkbox-div { margin-left: 5px; }
    </style>

    <div layout horizontal
      class = 'parent-container' > 
      <h-select-checkbox-menu
        id = 'unit-chkbox-menu'
        label = 'Unit'
        on-selectionchanged = '{{onSelectionChangedUnit }}'>  
        <template repeat = '{{ key in unitSelectItems.keys }}'>
          <h-select-item 
            label = '{{ key }}' 
            value = '{{ unitSelectItems[ key ] }}'>
          </h-select-item> 
        </template>
      </h-select-checkbox-menu>
    </div>
  </template>

   <script type = 'application/dart' src = 'unit_form.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The files are not in a specific named library - they are part of a dart project epimss_shared with the following folder structure

epimss_shared
 |
 lib
   |
   component
     |
     unit_form.html
     unit_form.dart

The exception refers to h-select-item from the imported html_component library from pub.org - specifically 'html_components/input/select_item.html'

I don't understand where the library is loaded from apart from the single import in unit_form.html.

I have read [Dart Exception: Already registered (Polymer) prototype for element x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376902/dart-exception-already-registered-polymer-prototype-for-element-x) and [Can't get Library in Dart to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482193/cant-get-library-in-dart-to-work-properly) but either did not help me to solve this issue.

I note that the issue is marked as resolved. If so why am I getting this error still.

Thanks

Comment: The issue is about two elements using the same code file, this doesn't seem to be what you are doing.

Comment: Yes. But the exception seems similar.

Comment: Yes. Maybe you run into another bug that leads to the same exception or more then one element use the same code file (maybe unintentionally). This didn't cause an exception until recently.

Comment: I will make a more detail check, but I doubt the use of same code use by two polymer custom element.

Comment: Doesn't the Polymer logging widget (bottom right corner on the page) show any warning or info about what could be wrong?

Comment: No. The only stacktrace is |Exception: Already registered (Polymer) prototype for element h-select-item (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:170)|

Comment: I have no code duplication. And still the problem persists. I downgraded to Dart 1.72 stable and still get the same error. I think the problem lies with polymer. Where can I find which version of polymer is compatible with Dart 1.7.2 - stable.

Comment: The most recent Polymer version should work with 1.7.2 without problems. If you are sure your code is OK you should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new. Probably send your project as personal mail to a member of the Polymer team so they are able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Bug report submitted at https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21439&thanks=21439&ts=1414455308